# iOS app for exporting HomeKit data?

Tags: software-recommendation, ios, csv

I have bought an [Elgato Eve](https://www.elgato.com/en/eve/eve-weather) HomeKit-compliant weather sensor. It works well enough but unfortunately its accompanying app does not support data export.

From what I understand about Apple HomeKit, other apps should be capable of accessing HomeKit data that is stored on the same device (as e.g. from the weather sensor), if I permit them to do so.

So is there a (perhaps generic) iOS app that would allow me to see all HomeKit data stored on my iPhone and to export it (e.g. send CSV file by e-mail, or similar).

**UPDATE** In terms of Apple's [HomeKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HomeKit/Reference/HomeKit_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014519) temperatures seem accessible as `HMCharacteristic`s e.g. of type `HMCharacteristicTypeCurrentTemperature` inside an `HMService` of type `HMServiceTypeThermostat`. I have not found yet whether the HomeKit framework natively supports the notion of historic data (e.g. past temperatures). Apple's [HMCatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/HomeKitCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app indicates that the specific device also maintains a number of private characteristics, some of which could (perhaps) be related to historic data. Alternatively it could also be that all temperatures arrive in Elegato Eve's app as notifications and that hence historic data is only supported on the level of this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to solve this as follows:

- use iTunes to sync from iOS to Mac to create unencrypted iPhone backup
- obtain and start [iPhone Backup Extractor](http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com) for OS X
- select latest backup, then Expert Mode, then Application Domains, then `com.elgato.eve`, `Documents`, `Elgato Systems##EveWeather##*sql` (`*` stands for what looks like a device serial number) and extract SQL file to `~/Desktop/`
- `sqlite3 ~/Desktop/Application\ Domains/com.elgato.eve/Documents/Elgato Systems##EveWeather##*sql` reveals that the database contains 3 tables, one for humidity, temperature, and air pressure each
- export tables e.g. to [CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675/how-do-i-dump-the-data-of-some-sqlite3-tables), then import e.g. into Excel

Comment: I should add that by now Elgato has added native CVS export capabilities into its app, so this workaround is no longer necessary.